# Binding to DataGridView Datasource property with List(Of Entity) throw a null reference exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I tried to make a solution for it for almost 4 hours but I couldn't find any

```
public class FinalClassScoreModel
{
    private readonly FinalClassScore _finalClassScore;

    public FinalClassScoreModel(FinalClassScore finalClassScore)
    {
        this._finalClassScore = finalClassScore;
    }

    public int EnrollId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.EnrollId;
        }
    }

    public string StudentNo
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Enroll.Student.StudentNo;
        }
    }

    public string ReversedName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Enroll.Student.ReversedName;
        }
    }

    public decimal? Prelim
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Prelim;
        }
    }

    public string PrelimE
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.PrelimE;
        }
    }

    public decimal? Midterm
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Midterm;
        }
    }

    public string MidtermE
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.MidtermE;
        }
    }

    public decimal? Final
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Final;
        }
    }

    public string FinalE
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.FinalE;
        }
    }

    public decimal? FinalGrade
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.FinalGrade;
        }
    }


    public bool IsDropped
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Enroll.IsDropped;
        }
    }

    public bool IsIncomplete
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Enroll.IsIncomplete;
        }
    }

    public bool IsGradeSubmitted
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Enroll.IsGradeSubmitted;
        }
    }


Public Property FinalClassScoreModels() As IEnumerable(Of FinalClassScoreModel) Implements IAlternativeView.FinalClassScoreModels
        Get
            Return Me._finalClassScoreModels
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As IEnumerable(Of FinalClassScoreModel))
            If DesignMode Then Exit Property
            Me._finalClassScoreModels = value
            Me.dgrAlternativeGrades.DataSource = Me._finalClassScoreModels
        End Set
    End Property
```

At first it was ok but when I delete 1 data on the FinalClassScoreModelList and re-run the `Me.dgrAlternativeGrades.Datasource = Me._finalClassScoreModels` it will throw `nullreference exception` on

```
public string StudentNo
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.Enroll.Student.StudentNo;
        }
    }
```

By the way it will work with no error if i didn't set the `datapropertyname` of each columns on `datagridview` but I need to set it because i dont want to autogenerate the columns.

my project is combination of vb.net and C#

Comment: sorry if you don't understand, I will just continue to try alternative solution if you think this question is not useful thank you

Comment: What is actually null? Have you tried breakpoints to find which object along that chain is firing the null exception? Is it possible to get a null Enroll or Student object? It's hard to determine anything from the code above.

Comment: Have you checked which property is null in `_finalClassScore` , `Enroll`, `Student`

Comment: Why are you mixing VB.Net in there, whats wrong with pure C#?

Comment: the code was originally written on vb.net windows form, I'am trying to migrate it with MVP pattern and in the future, make a web version using the pattern. I'am comfortable coding vb.net on windows form than C# and C# on web

Comment: @Lathejockey81 based on your comment, I found that if I tried to do this._finalClassScore.Enroll.Student.StudentNo and Enroll is null, it will raise an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those beginner who will also encounter this problem what I did on my FinalClassScoreModel class

```
public class FinalClassScoreModel
{
    private readonly FinalClassScore _finalClassScore;
    private readonly Enroll _enroll;

    public FinalClassScoreModel(FinalClassScore finalClassScore, Enroll enroll)
    {
        this._finalClassScore = finalClassScore;
        this._enroll = enroll;
    }

    public int EnrollId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._finalClassScore.EnrollId;
        }
    }

    public string StudentNo
    {
        get
        {
            return this._enroll.StudentNo;
        }
    }
```

on this way it will just get the value ot StudentNo even if it is null or not

thanks to all